# Problem running program in CMD when resizing

Tags: c++, cmd, clion

Down below I have a very simple program just to demonstrate the problem I'm having.
Basically I'm running the program in command line (Windows - CMD) through the IDE(Clion), so I made some configuration like:

[image: Configurations in IDE to launch with CMD]

But when I run the program the command window appears, but if I try to resize the command window the program advances and if i have a loop or something with getline the process enter in infinite looping.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Example:

[image: Example]

After trying to maximize the window:

[image: After trying to maximize the window]

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i=0;


    std::cout << "WHY!" << std::endl;

    do{
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout << "This is not working\n";
        ++i;
    }while(i<10);

return 0;
}
```

So basically, I want that the window resizing do not interfere with the normal flow of the program. It should just resizing the window, just like any other program.

Comment: Why are you using, 'Program arguments:' ```/C start cmd /c "tests.exe & pause"```? How does it differ from ```/D /C "tests.exe & Pause"```? I'm struggling to understand why you're opening a new cmd.exe instance from another cmd.exe instance, and immediately closing the initial instance.

Comment: yes, probably a better approach